# PHP global include?

Tags: php, file, include, global

I have a seperate PHP file I include that has a several important functions on it. I also have a file called variables.php which I include into each function so I can call some important variables too. Is there a way to just call variables.php at the top of the page, instead of inside each function manually? I just thought it would be easier if there was a way to do like a 'global' include or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if they are constant variables (AKA they don't change) you can define a constant instead

```
define("CONSTANT_NAME", "constant_value");
```

Or as of PHP5.3

```
const COSTANT_NAME="constant_value";
```

Then you can access them in every function

```
function test(){
    echo CONSTANT_NAME;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set `auto_prepend_file` in the INI or .htaccess file to automatically include a file.

Comment: do i just use ini_set to set it for the functions page only?

Comment: The auto_prepend_file only prepends it once BTW. At the beginning of the script.

Comment: `auto_prepend_file` will not solve the problem of variables being out of scope inside functions which I think is OPs original problem

Comment: I probably misunderstood ... are you trying to import variables into a local function scope? If so, I wouldn't really recommend that. You'd (generally) be better off including the variables once and using `$GLOBALS[]` to access it. You could put all of the variables into a single array to limit name collisions (or a static class, etc).